# Twilio Functions - SMS masking

Tags: node.js, sms, twilio

Hello I am quite new to Twilio, but I have tried to look up how to answer this question. I would like to use Twilio Functions to solve my problem. I was wondering if it is possible for two people to send SMS messages to each other without revealing either of their numbers.

I was hoping to do this with only one new number per pair.

I imagined it would be through a conditional statement, where person X sends a message to the twilio number and person Y receives it, and vice versa. I assume this cannot be done with the twiML bins because of this conditional statement.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: you can purchase a private number from Twilio.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/commerce-communications/masked-phone-numbers/build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could absolutely do this with Twilio Functions. Here's a simple example of using a number to mask SMS messages between two callers.

```
class NumberMapping {
  constructor() {
    this.mapping = {};
  }

  addMaskedPair(numberA, numberB, twilioNumber) {
    if (!this.mapping[twilioNumber]) {
      this.mapping[twilioNumber] = {};
    }
    this.mapping[twilioNumber][numberA] = numberB;
    this.mapping[twilioNumber][numberB] = numberA;
  }

  findNumber(from, to) {
    const numberPairs = this.mapping[to];
    if (!numberPairs) { return undefined; }
    return numberPairs[from];
  }
}

const numberMapping = new NumberMapping();
numberMapping.addMaskedPair('+1234567890', '+1098765432', '+1203948576');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const to = numberMapping.findNumber(event.From, event.To);
  if (typeof to !== 'undefined') {
    const response = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    response.message({ from: event.To, to: to }, event.Body);
    callback(null, response);
  } else {
    callback(new Error(`Number mapping couldn't be found for sender ${event.From} and Twilio number ${event.To}.`));
  }
};
```

The idea is that you create a `NumberMapping` object that maps between the two external numbers and your Twilio number. You add your mappings using:

```
numberMapping.addMaskedPair(firstNumber, secondNumber, twilioNumber);
```

and then when you need to retrieve the other number in a pair you can call

```
numberMapping.findNumber(number, twilioNumber);
```

The rest is just the function to return TwiML.

Note, you will only need as many Twilio numbers as there are relationships of the number that has the maximum set of relationships.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Philnash, you are everywhere! Thank you very much for this, it is super helpful and it has worked perfectly.

Comment: "Note, you will only need as many Twilio numbers as there are relationships of the number that has the maximum set of relationships."

Let us pretend that I have forgotten all of my math, could you explain this sentence in a simpler way?

Comment: Sorry, I found that hard to write too. The maximum number of Twilio phone numbers you need is equal to the maximum number of relationships one user's phone number has. That is, if you have 3 numbers in your system, 1 has a relationship to 1 other number and 1 has a relationship to 2 other numbers, then you need 2 Twilio numbers to manage this. You don't need a new Twilio number for every user in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase a number from twilio, then use node JS code to send and receive sms with it. You can also send voice messages too. The thing with twilio is that when you receive messages, twilio saves it to its website so you have to go to website and check it explicitly with your account.

You can create account and receive messages with [this link](https://www.twilio.com/login?g=%2Fconsole%2Fphone-numbers%2Fincoming&t=ca43129c60860927a579220072e505bc286f4c47cf367146e3c6ba077f98cdfd)

[Here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/your_response) is some tutorial on how to send messages, you have to choose node.JS option.